# Order data frame rows according to vector with priority order containing values not found in table

Tags: r

Is there a way to arrange rows in a data frame by a custom order, when the custom order contains values not found in the data frame?

```
order <- c("1", "2", "3A", "3B", "4", "R1", "R2", "O", "L")

df <- data.frame(name = letters[1:4], value = c("4", "2", "L", "O"))

> df
  name value
1    a     4
2    b     2
3    c     L
4    d     O

#Desired output
> df
  name value
1    b     2
2    a     4
3    d     O
4    c     L
```

I am trying to make a generic script for order, thus I need to keep the order vector as is to account for all cases. I have tried factor and arrange methods without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `ordered` `factor`:

```
df[order(ordered(df$value, order)),]
#  name value
#2    b     2
#1    a     4
#4    d     O
#3    c     L
```

This is confusing however since you have named your ordering vector `order`, which is also used for the `order()` function. It is somewhat easier to understand if you edit this.

```
vecord <- c("1", "2", "3A", "3B", "4", "R1", "R2", "O", "L")
df[order(ordered(df$value, vecord)),]
#  name value
#2    b     2
#1    a     4
#4    d     O
#3    c     L
```

This allows you to specify a priority, even if the values aren't yet present in the set, and might be added later.

```
ordered(df$value, vecord)
#[1] 4 2 L O
#Levels: 1 < 2 < 3A < 3B < 4 < R1 < R2 < O < L
```

Comment: Can this be combined with a secondary sort operation, like desc(name), if there are two or value identical values?

Comment: @AFontana - whoops, missed this comment. Yep, you can add more values in `order`. In this case something like `df[order(ordered(df$value, vecord), -xtfrm(df$name) ),]` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can similarly do this with `match` and `order`.

```
df[order(match(df$value, order)), ]

#  name value
#2    b     2
#1    a     4
#4    d     O
#3    c     L
```